# Drive Api auth suddenly fails

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, google-drive-api, google-api-console

My Android apps were up and running for half a year and over one year. One can cast movies from Google Drive to the Chromecast the other can stream music from Google Drive to the device.

Since about two days this:

```
Drive.files().listFiles()
```

throws this:

```
W/System.err﹕ com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
W/System.err﹕ {
W/System.err﹕ "code": 403,
W/System.err﹕ "errors": [
W/System.err﹕ {
W/System.err﹕ "domain": "usageLimits",
W/System.err﹕ "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.",
W/System.err﹕ "reason": "accessNotConfigured"
W/System.err﹕ }
W/System.err﹕ ],
W/System.err﹕ "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
W/System.err﹕ }
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
W/System.err﹕ at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
```

All projects which use the Drive Api were removed from the api console. It seems like they weren't completely deleted, because I can access one of the projects, which had billing enabled through the 'Billings' tab, project number: 340185983176. 
The cloud storage for the one project where I used it, was disabled and all files from the this project were deleted two days later.

So why do I post this here ? Because I am told to do so:

Google Cloud storage suggests using SO:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/resources-support#support-packages

Google Drive Api suggests using SO:

https://developers.google.com/drive/support

Google Cloud suggests using SO:

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/3466163

All I want to know, is why the projects were disabled ?

Comment: Any particular reason you included the GCS tag? As far as I understand (as per your description) streaming is done from Drive rather than from GCS. If you expect to receive the reason for projects deletion I recommend you to provide corresponding Project IDs.

Comment: The cloud storage (where I hosted the LocalCast receiver app) was disabled too, which caused an app outtake for half a day until i noticed it. If you tell me how i should look up the ids of the deleted projects I'll gladly do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out the only owner of this project was marked mistakenly as a hijacked account, and thus disabled. This also disabled the project and this caused the errors.

Stefan, thanks for your collaboration (and patience) in investigating this.